# Use of a string to get information in an associative array

Tags: actionscript-2

I've got a function that takes two strings as arguments, and I want to use these arguments to get the data held in associative arrays.

```
var myVar:Object = {};

myVar.value = 10;

function getStuff(v:String, vl:String){

//...

}
```

In this case, `v` = `"myVar"` and `vl` = `"value"`.

How do I translate `v`into the variable name `'myVar'` and `v1` into `'value'` so that I can access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this won't work, for I can only test AS3 here, but please try this:

```
function getStuff(v:String, vl:String){
  return eval(v + "." + vl);
}
```

eventually

```
function getStuff(v:String, vl:String){
  return eval("_gobal." + v + "." + vl);
}
```